# Delete additional files using custom action VS 2010

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, setup-deployment, custom-action

after uninstalling my app , i want to delete the app folderunder the user profile.

**C:\Users\User\AppData\Local\App_Folder_Nane**

I read about custom action, creating a dll and add it to the setup package or create a batch. but what i am looking for, is a sample example to see how the custom action work. so any links or piece of code will be welcome.

thank you

Answer (score 0):

Start with this:

https://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/visual-studio/visual-studio-setup---projects-and-custom-actions/

This is vb but the general idea is all there:

http://vbcity.com/forums/t/145818.aspx

Or at its simplest, just write an exe to do the removal and run it as an uninstall custom action by adding it there in the setup IDE.